# How to save full tensorflow model from google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I trained a computer vision model in google colab.

Now I want to get it to my computer to work with it.

If I do `model.save("name.h5")` and then download the .h5 file, does this save the trained model?

Or is it just the untrained structure of the model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `model.save("name.h5")` saves the trained model. Of course, you should execute this line after you have trained/fit the model.

However, `model.save()` only saves the model structure and the updated weights. And it does not store any loss function weights and information of the loss function. Therefore, you should avoid re-training your model after loading it from the saved file.

If you are willing to further re-train your model, you should use `tf.keras.models.save_model()` to save a model, and `tf.keras.models.load_model()` to load a model. Further information can be found in the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/#wholemodel-saving-amp-loading).

Comment: "And it does not store any weights" this looks wrong, it contradicts what you said earlier. model.save does save the model's weights.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote in such a way that you misunderstood it. Therefore, I have edited the answer. I would like to add some information further. Sometimes Keras loss functions contain important weights that are used to train the model. Using `model.save()` does not save the loss function weights. However, this should not cause any problem if you are not willing to pre-trained a saved model. Thanks.